# Bash script loop through subdirectories and write to file without using find,ls etc

Tags: bash, shell, unix, recursion

Sorry for asking this question again. I have already received answer but with using `find` but unfortunately I need to write it without using any predefined commands.

I am trying to write a script that will loop recursively through the subdirectories in the current directory. It should check the file count in each directory. If file count is greater than 10 it should write all names of these file in file named "BigList" otherwise it should write in file "ShortList". This should look like:

```
---<directory name>
<filename>
<filename>
<filename>
<filename>
....
---<directory name>
<filename>
<filename>
<filename>
<filename>
....
```

My script only works if subdirectories don't include subdirectories in turn. 
I am confused about this because it doesn't work as I expect.
Here is my script

```
#!/bin/bash
parent_dir=""
if [ -d "$1" ]; then
    path=$1;
else
    path=$(pwd)
fi
parent_dir=$path
loop_folder_recurse() { 
    local files_list=""      
    local cnt=0
    for i in "$1"/*;do
        if [ -d "$i" ];then
            echo "dir: $i"
            parent_dir=$i               
            echo before recursion
            loop_folder_recurse "$i"
            echo after recursion
            if [ $cnt -ge 10 ]; then
                echo -e "---"$parent_dir >> BigList
                echo -e $file_list >> BigList
            else
                echo -e "---"$parent_dir >> ShortList
                echo -e $file_list >> ShortList
            fi
        elif [ -f "$i" ]; then
            echo file $i
            if [ $cur_fol != $main_pwd ]; then
                file_list+=$i'\n'
                cnt=$((cnt + 1))
            fi
        fi
    done
}
echo "Base path: $path"
loop_folder_recurse $path
```

How can I modify my script to produce the desired output?

Comment: Does it have to be bash? It may be something that's easier in perl.

Comment: try to use `ls -d $1/*/` so that you'll get only the directories, and be able to pass them to your next recursion with a full path already.

Comment: also you can try using `ls -p | grep /` to get only the files and `ls -p | grep -v /` to get only the directories

Comment: I can't use any default programm

Comment: I was wondering if you tried my solution? If so, did it work?

Answer (score 0):

This bash script produces the output that you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

bigfile="$PWD/BigList"
shortfile="$PWD/ShortList"
shopt -s nullglob

loop_folder_recurse() {
    ( 
        [[ -n "$1" ]] && cd "$1"
        for i in */; do
            [[ -d "$i" ]] && loop_folder_recurse "$i"
            count=0
            files=''
            for j in *; do
                if [[ -f "$j" ]]; then          
                    files+="$j"$'\n'
                    ((++count))
                fi
            done
            if ((count > 10)); then 
                outfile="$bigfile"
            else 
                outfile="$shortfile"
            fi
            echo "$i" >> "$outfile"
            echo "$files" >> "$outfile"
        done
    )
}

loop_folder_recurse
```

#### Explanation

`shopt -s nullglob` is used so that when a directory is empty, the loop will not run. The body of the function is within `( )` so that it runs within a subshell. This is for convenience, as it means that the function returns to the previous directory when the subshell exits.

Hopefully the rest of the script is fairly self-explanatory but if not, please let me know and I will be happy to provide additional explanation.